# given coordinates, find the number at that coordinates in spiral matrix.

Tags: matrix-equations

[image: This is the spiral]

given coordinates, find the number at that coordinates in spiral matrix.
Given is the image of spiral i am talking about.

at
0,0  ---> 0

0,1  ---> 1

1,1  ---> 2

0,1  ---> 3

-1,1  ---> 4

-1,0  ---> 5

-1,-1  ---> 6

And the answer is here, but i don't know how to reach to this solution.
[image]

Somebody please give proof, how to reach to these equations.

Comment: In the diagram it's $(1,0) \to 1$ but your description has $(0,1) \to 1$ [and later to $3$ as in the diagram]. I once messed around with exactly this spiral, trying for the function $K(x,y)$. Interesting that someone has figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempted explanation of the first formula. It applies only in the open region to the right of the two lines $y=\pm x.$ If we show it is right when $y=0$ it will follow, since then the added $y$ will make it OK on the vertical line through $(x,0)$ while staying in the region.

A few sketches show that if we remove the points on the vertical line through $(x,0)$ with $y\le 0,$ what is left is a square of lattice points of side $2x-1.$ Then we need to add $x$ more, to account for the vertical part removed. But we also need to subtract one since the labeling starts at $0$ for the origin. This gives us
$$(2x-1)^2+x-1=4x^2-3x,$$
which then on adding $y$ as noted to account for where one is on the last vertical part of the journey, gives the desired formula $4x^2-3x+y.$

The others are likely doable in a similar way, I'd suggest looking for a convenient point on an axis for a starting idea, and after some sketches finding a square (or maybe a rectangle near square) of lattice points which preceed your chosen axis point.